# retrieve data from a column that mapped as array

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hql, hibernate-mapping

I'm using hibernate mapping as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
      <class entity-name="TestClass.TestClass" table="TestClass">
        <id name="id" type="integer" unsaved-value="any">
          <column name="TestClassId" not-null="true" />
          <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

        <array name="arrayProp " table="arrayProp ">
          <key column="id" />
          <index column="ordre" />
          <element column="arrayItem" type="string" />
        </array>

     </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

now I want to retrieve te elements stored in arrayProp,
I writted this query:

```
select arrayProp from TestClass
```

and all I get is :

```
 Wrapped Exception: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode 
     \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'arrayProp' {originalText=arrayProp}
```

anyone knows how to retrieve data from arrayProp, thanx for help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use query:

```
String queryText = "select tableClass.arrayProp from TableClass";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryText);
```

Then when you will use query.list() I think you get List (or List like in JPA, I'm not sure). If you will getList, then first element of the Object[] array will be your array of strings String[].

Comment: thx @dimas,

I tried using table names and table alias but it won't work.
i think I need to use a join between the TestClass table and the arrayProp